# What is the equivalent of late | lazy | lateinit in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, null, initialization, option-type, lazy-initialization

Dart, Kotlin and Swift have a lazy initialization keyword that lets you avoid the usage of Optional type mainly for maintainability reason.

```
// Using null safety:
class Coffee {
  late String _temperature;

  void heat() { _temperature = 'hot'; }
  void chill() { _temperature = 'iced'; }

  String serve() => _temperature + ' coffee';
}
```

What does TypeScript has as equivalent ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The closest is a [definite-assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization). This tells typescript "i know it looks like i didn't initialize this, but trust me, i did".

```
class Coffee {
  private _temperature!: string; // Note the !

  heat() { this._temperature = "hot"; }
  chill() { this._temperature = "iced"; }

  serve() { 
    return this._temperature + ' coffee';
  }
}
```

Be aware that when you use type assertions, you are telling typescript not to check your work. If you assert that it's defined, but you forget to actually call the code that makes it be defined, typescript will not tell you about this at compile time and you may get an error at run time.

Comment: Thank you, but I did not understand your warning here: "use type assertions, you are telling typescript not to check your work. If you make a mistake, typescript will not tell you about it." if I understand, this will give "Could not find length propName of undefined" if I call _temperature.length?

Comment: If you access _temperature.length, typescript will not give you any compile time warnings, because you've told it to assume that it's a string. But if that assertion was wrong (ie, you have a bug in your code, and are not actually making sure it's defined in all cases), then it's possible you'll get an exception at runtime