# Make properties of object optional, define them later and use them without verification

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would to know if there is a workaround on types definition, i'm not sure to correclty explain it, so i'll give an exemple.

I would like to define a type which is an big object containing multiple objects.

```
type BigObject = {
 dom: HTMLElement,
 count: number
}
```

This object is defined in a constructor of a class, but by a function called in the constructor

```
class Starter {

  bigObject: BigObject;

  constructor() {
    // A lot of code here, so I can't pollute more
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    this.bigObject.dom = document.getElementByID("app");
    this.bigObject.count = 0; 
  }
}
```

Firstly, when I define the props in constructor, this is ok, but when I define it ine the initialize function (even if called in constructor), TypeScript say me that object has no initializer ...

Secondly, this object will transports useful datas over my app, I would like to use it somewhere else. I would like to not define its props as possibly undefined (question mark), because I make a lot of verification with throws and I'm totally sure that its props are defined when I use it. More than that, because I will use it really often, I don't want to verify if `bigObject.dom` is defined each time I use it.

---

So when I make question marks, the definition of this objet is good in the `Starter` class but I have to make verifications when I use it.
When I don't make question marks, I don't have to make verifications when I use it but its definition fails.

Could someone help me please ?

> I tried to make a basic exemple of my use case, but in reality, it is a game engine. So the "BigObject" corresponds to an object with services which are transported all over the app. And the "when I use it" means when the game engine has started and the definition of those services has been checked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843040/what-is-the-equivalent-of-late-lazy-lateinit-in-typescript

Comment: Well the property *does* not have an initialiser anywhere in your code. The application will crash when you try to instantiate a `new Starter`.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely need to initialise the property when your `Starter` instance is constructed. You cannot avoid it. There are two basic ways to do it:

- in the constructor:

  ```
  class Starter {
    bigObject: BigObject;
    constructor() {
      // …
      this.bigObject = {
        dom: document.getElementByID("app"),
        count: 0,
      };
    }
  }
  ```
- as a class field:

  ```
  class Starter {
    bigObject: BigObject = {
      dom: document.getElementByID("app"),
      count: 0,
    };
    constructor() {
      // …
    }
  }
  ```

Now you say

> A lot of code [in the constructor], so I can't pollute more

That is where you should use a helper function. In your case, you don't even have lots of `Starter` properties, but you already grouped them together in a `BigObject`, which makes it even easier to build the entire object elsewhere than in the constructor. A method like `initialise` could do it, but I would recommend to avoid that. You'd need to call it on a not-yet-initialised instance, you might actually forget to call it, and Typescript will still complain. Better, make a helper that *returns* the big object. You can make it a top-level free function or a `static` class method. Then just call that from the constructor (or the class field initialiser). You could even make the `bigObject` a parameter of your constructor.